# Return false and rollback in after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In ActiveRecord model after_save callback I need to ROLLBACK transaction and return false.

```
def after_save_callback
  if mycondition?
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

This callback rolls-back transaction but mymodel.save! returns true. How to make it return false and rollback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `after_save` You should be looking at `around_save` instead:

```
def around_save
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    yield # calls the actual save method
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if my_condition?
  end
end
```

Comment: Rails wraps `Model#save` in a transaction anyway.  You should not be opening a second transaction inside of the around_save hook.  Rather, you should just raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback`.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to abort a save in an `after_save` callback, you should

```
raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self)
```

rather than

```
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
```

This will not only roll back the transaction (callbacks always happen inside a possibly-implicit transaction as part of the `save` or `create`) but also cause `save` to return `false`.

Here is an article with more details: http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2013/05/23/rollback-after-save/

Answer (score 9):

```
def around_save
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # this will actually ROLLBACK
    yield # calls the actual save method
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # this will cause a COMMIT!!! because it affect only this internal transaction.
    # OTHER ACTIONS NOT EXECUTED BUT BEING A INTERNAL TRANSACTION, THE PARENT WILL COMMIT, because parent hasn't failed.
  end
end
```

So... I think around_save come already on a transaction block, so you don't need to add that extra ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do block because rollbacks doesnt propagate up

So if you want to rollback before or after yield, you need to remove that internal transaction.

```
def around_save
  #ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # this will actually ROLLBACK
    yield # calls the actual save method
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # this will actually ROLLBACK
  # end
end
```

**EDIT:** Reading what I wrote... now seem difficult to understand. The point is: if you are gonna use `aroud_save` don't wrapp again with `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` (**do like in the last example**) because rails will wrap the call to `around_save` with is own `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` so when you `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` you are only rolling back the most internal transaction, so you can end with extrange results and partial saves (like in the first example whic is **FAIL**).